# Redshift connection error : could not find function "JDBC"

Tags: r, rstudio, amazon-redshift

When executing the code verbatim from the [Amazon reference](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-r-with-amazon-redshift/), the driver function is not found. I've installed and loaded the RJDBC package, however, the JDBC function cannot be found. Please forgive the output below. I included it to show the verbatim code from the reference is returning an error for me.

platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin15.6.0
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0
status
major          3
minor          5.1
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
nickname       Feather Spray

```
> library(RJDBC)
Loading required package: rJava
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
> 
> # download Amazon Redshift JDBC driver
> download.file('http://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar','RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar')
trying URL 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar'
Content type 'application/x-java-archive' length 2055261 bytes (2.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.0 MB

> 
> # connect to Amazon Redshift
> driver <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver", "RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar", identifier.quote="`")
Error in JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver", "RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar",  : 
  could not find function "JDBC"
```

Comment: You did not successfully install rJava. You need to install Java runtime in advance per the message. It is free from Oracle: [Java SE Runtime](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html).

Comment: Ah thanks. I tried reinstalling rJava and the Java toolkit etc, but am still having problems. I understand that Mac and Java can sometimes not get along nicely. I'll look into this more.